# How to Trigger Browser Refresh when Django Static Files Change

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, livereload

I'm building a Django/React app and trying to automatically refresh the page whenever static files change (e.g. webpack bundle that's generated whenever React code is updated). I've tried the following packages: [python-livereload](https://github.com/lepture/python-livereload), [django-livereload](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-livereload), and [django-livereload-server](https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server). None worked. And, they don't appear to be actively maintained. Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you experiencing this behavior during local development or in production or both?

Comment: Development. I haven't tried in production, but I tried changing debug to false, which had no effect.